# Eclipse stop responding when running a java program

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package com.selenium;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Exxcel {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception,NullPointerException{
    //WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    //WebElement wb;
    String Value;
    try{
    FileInputStream file= new FileInputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\OMEGA\\Desktop\\Test Planning And Documents\\Automation Data.xlsx");
    Workbook data=WorkbookFactory.create(file);
    Sheet sheet=data.getSheet("Sheet1");
    for(int i=1;i<=sheet.getLastRowNum();i++){
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        if(row != null){
        // Putting condition to check row is null or not
            for (int j = 1; j < row.getLastCellNum();) {
            if (row.getCell(j) != null) {
                // Putting condition to check row cell is null or not
                String value=row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                Value=value;
                //String value1=row.getCell(j+1).getStringCellValue();
                String[] array= new String[2];
                array[0]=Value;
                //array[1]=value1;
                if( array[0] != null  ) {
                    // Putting condition to check array[] is null or not
                    System.out.println(array[0]); 
                    //System.out.println(array[1]);
                 }   
                }
            }  
        }
      } 
    }catch(NullPointerException n){
        n.printStackTrace();
        //System.out.println("Null");
        }// catch
    }//main
}//class
```

This is the code which i am trying to run but as soon as i click on run buton the entier eclipse stops responding. Don't know why its happening?

Comment: any logs, hints to show that the program is still *running*?

Comment: Debug your code to make your life easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that your loop never ends:

```
 for (int j = 1; j < row.getLastCellNum();) {
```

I don't see `j` being incremented anywhere in your code.

An infinite loop on the main GUI thread would have the side-effect to freeze the IDE.

---

As the [OP Shantanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2675355/shantanu) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604528/eclipse-stop-responding-when-running-a-java-program/24656669#comment38123713_24604551), adding an increment j++ was enough to resolve the situation:

```
for(int j=0; j<=row.getLastRowNumber(); j++) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. While debugging i had't not checked the  2nd for loop condition and yes because of that the program was going into the infinite loop. Did the code changes and put a increment(j++)  and its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You must put an increment or decrement operater on the second for loop. You have not put any condition in the second loop which is why your program is going in an infinite loop and eclipse becomes slow in performance.

Change your code with:

```
for(int j=0; j<=row.getLastRowNumber(); j++)
{
  //Your Code
}
```

Comment: How is that any different from my answer, and the OP's conclusion? (both done 2 days ago)